# How to sum a column cell if the data cell have string character and number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to ask all the expert here as I don't know where to refer.

May I know how to sum the data cell that have character and number in one cell?
Because this data I've downloaded from system.
The data is not in currency format.

[image: Example]

How to sum all of these? as i try to use =SUM, the output is 0.
Appreciate if anyone help me on this.

Thank you.

I try to use =SUM, the output is 0.

Comment: Do you just need to exclude the "RM" in every cell? or is every cell different?

Comment: Try `=SUM(--TEXTAFTER(B2:B4," "))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attempted something. First you need to extract the number part of the text to a separate column. Then you need to use the VALUE function to convert this number part to an actual number.

My spreadsheet looks like this.

[image: Excel Image]

Is this something you are looking for? There are 2 formulas here.
In the column under text, you need to put this formula.

`=RIGHT(G6,LEN(G6)-MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},G6&"0123456789"))+1)`

In the column that says "Convert 2 number", you need to enter this formula.

`=VALUE(I6)`

The data in my spreadsheet is in columns, G, I and J. You may need to change your formula based on the location of the cell in your spreadsheet.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this, but for readability & usage I will use `TEXTAFTER()` as mentioned above by **[VBasic2008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9814069/vbasic2008)** Sir, or use `SUBSTITUTE()` function.

---

[image]

---

```
=SUM(--TEXTAFTER(B1:B3," "))
```

---

Or, if one not using `MS365` then

```
=SUM(--SUBSTITUTE(B1:B3,"RM ",))
```

---

Also it is highly suggested, instead of using `RM 45.00` `RM 30.00` etc, use custom formatting to show the `RM` --> `"RM "#,##0.00` it becomes easier to sum then.

[image]

---

Another alternative to use `REPLACE()` function:

[image]

---

```
=SUM(--REPLACE(B1:B3,1,3,))
```

---